# Do skeleton traps get hurt by poison spell?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I was attacking a TH9 guy, and I had poison spell at that time. There was a skeleton trap activated and lots of troops just covering the skeletons, so I mistakenly dropped the poison there over those skeletons. So, I am wondering from that time: Do the skeletons got hurt or not? I was able to watch the replay but the troops had fully covered those skeletons. If someone knows please answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

### Poison Spell Summary

This is one of 3 new spells in Clash of Clans which have been added since the July 1st update.
Once you have the Dark Spell Factory, you can brew this spell.
*This spell deals damage too all enemy troops, Heroes and Skeletons trap and slows them as long as they are not staying idle.*
This spell doesn’t damage buildings inside its area.

[Source.](http://cocland.com/guides/poison-spell-guide)

Comment: but i mean to the skeletons present in skeleton traps